# Unable to locate Remotion.Linq >= 2.0.0-alpha-002

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kruntime, kpm, coreclr

I have updated my KRE to `beta-11087`.
Running `kpm restore` on my project gives such a error : 'Unable to locate **Remotion.Linq** >= 2.0.0-alpha-002'.

Is there anyone who has the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/325 this might indicate that you're missing a NuGet feed. Check that you have the nuget.org feed enabled.

Comment: @Mike, can you indicatie which nuget package did solve your probleem?